# Live broadcast camera and microphone without flash

Tags: flash, websocket, streaming, red5

I am building a live virtual class room and I need to broadcast the teacher camera and microphone to many students. Previously the broadcasting was implemented using red5 via rtmp protocol which is flash.

But the problem is Android phones does not support flash. Also if you take webrtc, it is peer to peer. Due to the requirements of the system, I need a non peer to peer solution

My question is, is there a way to broadcast webcam and mic to many students at the same time efficiently without using flash? If not what other options do I have to achieve this?

Also is there a way to broadcast both cam and mic via web-sockets ? I'd like to do this as an opensource project since I did not find any good solution for this problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use flash and you are leaning towards WebRTC, I suggest that you check out licode. It is a capable server that allows you to use both the cam and mic via javascript.

http://lynckia.com/licode/

Red5 on the other hand will have WebRTC support, but not any time soon.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

- [Obs project](http://obsproject.com/forum/threads/how-to-stream-on-linux.4594/)
- [Open tok](http://tokbox.com/opentok)

Answer (score 1):

**WebRTC** is the best option you can use.

Go through their documentation its pretty easy to create a full functional video chat application by only using javascript and plugin free WebRTC.

[WebRTC Basics](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/)

[WebRTC Official Site](http://www.webrtc.org/)